# Accessing modified attributes in katharsis when saving resource

Tags: katharsis

When I implement a method annotated with @JsonApiSave in my katharsis repository I get a fully populated resource as a parameter, even though the PATCH request is only sending a single attribute. Is there a way I can find out which attributes have been updated?

Comment: Where exactly is your error occurring? You may also have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Im not getting an error, I just need to find out what properties changed. What would be useful is if Katharsis could pass this through to the method for example  
`@JsonApiSave
    public Resource save(Resource resource, String [] modifiedAttributes)`

Comment: @RobMartin did you ever find a way to do this? I have the same need :)